# Minimum (positive) floating point number (closest to zero)

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point

I'm trying to find the minimum (positive) value (closest to zero) that I can store in a single precission floating point number. Using the `<limits>` header I can get the value, but if I make it much smaller, the float can still hold it and it gives the right result. Here is a test program, compiled with g++ 5.3.0.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a = numeric_limits<float>::max();    
    float b = numeric_limits<float>::min(); 

    a = a*2;
    b = b/pow(2,23);
    

    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

As I expected, "a" gives infinity, but "b" keeps holding the good result even after dividing the minimum value by 2^23, after that it gives 0.

The value that gives `numeric_limits<float>::min()` is 2^(-126) which I belive is the correct answer, but why is the float on my progam holding such small numbers?

Comment: Are you considering denormals?

Comment: You need to multiply FLOAT_MIN by FLOAT_EPSILON in order to get the smallest positive float. Otherwise, just using FLOAT_MIN, you get the smallest normal positive float.

Comment: @void_ptr I didn't know about that, but they seem to be the answer

Comment: Try `nextafter (0.0f, 1.0f)`. This will find the next representable floating-point number, starting at zero and progressing in the direction of unity.

Comment: @njuffa That works for doubles, for floats it gives me 0.

Comment: It should not. You may need to compile with compiler switches set for full IEEE-754 compliance. These switches are toolchain specific, e.g. `/fp:strict`. Even if FTZ (flush-to-zero) mode is in effect and denormals are therefore not supported, (note that FTZ is not part of the IEEE-754 floating-point standard), `nextafterf(0.0f, 1.0f)` should return a sensible answer, such as 2**-126. Otherweise I would consider it broken.

Comment: Since you want a `float` result, using `nextafterf (0.0f, 1.0f)` [note trailing `f` in function name] may work better, although I was under the impression that `nexafter` is properly overloaded for 'float' and 'double'.

Comment: @njuffa Yes, that worked

Comment: @njuffa: I don't know about "properly."  The C++ committee was fairly haphazard when choosing which functions to overload and how.

Comment: I tried to determine whether `nextafter()` should be overloaded for `float` and `double` in C++11, and based on the standards document I thought it should. However, the C++11 compiler I tried apparently disagrees, since `nextafter (0.0f, 1.0f)` returns zero, which would imply that `nextafter()` is a double-precision function. A subsequent internet search did not bring clarity either, which is why I refrained from posting an answer and merely provided a comment.

Comment: I edited the question so the answer is no longer simply zero.

Answer (score 6):

`std::numeric_limits::min` for floating-point types gives the smallest non-zero value that can be represented without loss of precision. `std::numeric_limits::lowest` gives the smallest representable value. With IEEE representations that's a **subnormal** value (previously called denormalized).

Answer (score 3):

From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format:

> The minimum positive normal value is 2^−126 ≈ 1.18 × 10^−38 and the
>   minimum positive (denormal) value is 2^−149 ≈ 1.4 × 10^−45.

So, for

```
cout  << (float)pow(2,-149) 
      << "-->" << (float)pow(2,-150) 
      << "-->" <<  (float)pow(2,-151) << endl;
```

I'm getting:

```
1.4013e-45-->0-->0
```

Comment: That returns the lowest number (most negative) but not the smallest (closest to zero)

Comment: Thank you, Msegade for pointing that out; I was kind of too hasty that I did not read the question carefully! I edited my response to properly answer the question in hand.

Answer (score -4):

> I'm trying to find the minimum value (closest to zero) that I can
> store in a single precission floating point number

0 is the closest value to 0 that you can store in any precision float.  In fact, you can store it two ways, as there is a positive and negative 0.

edit: I edited the question to specify positive but this was the correct answer for what was originally asked.

Comment: It's obvious OP means the smallest number _greater than zero_